# Calculating monthly and annual payments with corresponding rate: different results?

Tags: mortgage, compound-interest

Good evening everyone,

I got a small financial problem that I tried to understand and, even though I come to the right answer, I do not understand why my alternative approach does not work.

Problem: you want to buy a flat for €150,000 so you ask for a mortgage to your bank which offers you an effective annual interest rate of 15%. The payments you have to make are monthly and the time span you need for reimbursing is 10 years. **How much do you have to pay at the end of each month?**

Well, to find the monthly payment (= % for interests + % for principal), we first need to convert that effective annual rate to its monthly counterpart: i = (1+0.15)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.0017149 = 1.1749%

Then, by using the annuity formula, we have a factor of i*(1+i)^n / i so 64.261 where i = 1.1749% from above and n = 120 as 120 months in 10 years.

Then, to get the monthly payment, we simply divide the principal by the factor: €150,000/64.261 = €2334.22 per month to reimburse.

What I do no get is the mistake I make in the alternative approach without using a monthly rate: we simply calculate the annuity factor with r = 15%, compute our yearly payment and we get €150,000/5.284 = €29,887.81. **This value, when divided by 12 (to get the monthly payment), however does not give the €2334.22 from above.**

When writing those lines, I reckon it is because the payment has to be done monthly and not yearly. Therefore, how could we convert the 15% to get a yearly rate which takes into account the fact that our payments are done monthly ? I guess it has something to do with the compounding interest formula: (1+r) = (1+(i/n))^(n*t) but I am a bit lost...

Any help on how to solve the problem with this alternative view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When writing those lines, I reckon it is because the payment has to be done monthly and not yearly.

Correct. If interest is only charged annually, you get a $29,887.81 annual payment, which is different than making 12 payments of 1/12 of that amount (less interest will be paid as the principal is paid down each month)

> Therefore, how could we convert the 15% to get a yearly rate which takes into account the fact that our payments are done monthly ?

You'd have to calculate the monthly annuity factor, multiply it by 12, and solve the annuity factor formula for `i`. Since there's no algebraic way to reverse the annuity factor formula to solve for `i`, there's not a formula to calculate the equivalent "annual" rate based on a periodic payment without going through the monthly conversion first.

Comment: Huge thanks for your complete answer! That was a perfect explanation, I got an i of 13.332% (solved with the RATE formula from Excel) and yearly payments of €28,010.656 which are indeed 12*€2,334.22!